# Why is my CSS for removing border-right on a class being ignored?

Tags: css, html-lists, border, css-specificity

In my code I got border-right on all of my `li` elements. I'm trying to get rid of the border-right when a `li` element is active using an own made class named active. The problem is that my class does not remove the border-right.

This is a JSFiddle of the code as well: http://jsfiddle.net/t0a4j5tq/2/

```css
div#navbar {
 width: 250px;
 height: 550px;
 float: left;
}

div#navbar > ul {
 text-align: center; 
 background-color: #EEE;
}

div#navbar > ul > li.li, div#navbar > ul > li.liLast {
 list-style-type: none;
 border-bottom: 1px solid black; 
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 25px;
 font-family: Algerian, "Times New Roman";
}

div#navbar > ul > li > a {
 color: black;
 text-decoration: none;
 display: block;
 width: 100%;
 padding: 38px 0;
 
 -webkit-transition: margin-left 0.5s;
}

div#navbar > ul > li > a:hover {
 color: white;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 1px black, 1px 0 black, 0 -1px black, 0 0 5px black;
 margin-left: 5px;
}

li.active {
    box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #333;
    border-right: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="navbar">
 <ul>
  <li class="li active"><a href="index.html">Start</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="./undersidor/omMig.html">Om mig</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="./undersidor/vision.html">Vision</a></li>
  <li class="li"><a href="./undersidor/tjanster.html">Tjänster</a></li>
  <li class="liLast"><a href="./undersidor/kontakt.html">Kontakt</a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't see any `.active` class in your CSS. That's definitely a problem, if that's how you're trying to achieve this. There also doesn't seem to be a `border-right` applied to the `li` element you have class `.active` on... so there's nothing to remove.

Comment: My bad. Forgot to include .active in the example above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root of your problem is [CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity). This is important to understand, because simply using `!important` in your code is a hack and can cause you to have problems later on if you forget that you put it there.

`!important` overrides **everything**, and so obviously should not be used except in dire, last-resort situations (and even then, many people [myself included] would argue that you should figure out how to fix the problem anyway instead of using `!important`).

Earlier in your code, you have a CSS selector for the same element (and similar elements):

```
div#navbar > ul > li.li {
```

Now, you are trying to access the same element with just this:

```
li.active {
```

But the first selector is *way* more [specific](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/27/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/). Instead, you should use the following CSS selector, **without** the `!important` hack:

```
div#navbar > ul > li.active {
```

Answer (score -1):

Hi solution is simple you just need to inform that this change is "important" :P

```
li.active {
box-shadow: inset 3px 3px 10px #333;
border-right-style: none !important;}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Omg, it was really that simple!
Really appreciate the quick response.

Comment: There is a way to do this without using CSS hacks.

Comment: Care to share, @TylerH? And, is !important not a good solution?

Comment: @Turlestew See my answer for why !important is not a good solution